# What is the best way to maintain translations of a user guide website?

Tags: html, translation

I have static HTML files of a Japanese user guide website which I need to translate into English every time they come out with a new version. I've been using html2pot and using pootle to translate, then converting back with po2html.

I'm thinking there must be a better way though, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

You can use World Lingo to translate the site and then save the source. I just tried this on my homepage and it worked fine.
http://www.worldlingo.com/en/websites/url_translator.html

Or you can install a dynamic translator on the page. I found this blog entry that explains how to do that: http://labnol.blogspot.com/2005/11/add-language-translation-to-website.html

It depends on whether you need to save the result or if this is just to be able to have different users view the site in their language.